# How to insert line break after every complete number of three words?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8, line-breaks

I want to insert a line break `<br/>` after every complete three words of a sentence or paragraph using `Javascript` or `typescript` or `angular 8`.

```
let temText = 'Dummy text refers to the bits of content that are used to fill a website mock-up.';

let info = temText.replace(/(.{40})/g, '$1<br>');
console.log('After Break: ', info);
```

In this way, the break line inserts exactly 40 characters after.
But I want to insert the break line after complete three words.

Comment: You are using Regex, so you need to use a regex where it looks for 3 spaces, not just 40 characters. I don't quite have that answer but that should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

this is where javascript reduce comes in handy, you can tailor it on your own needs..

```
  const paragraph = "Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook"


let paragraphWithBreaks = paragraph.split(' ')
 .reduce((accum, curr, idx) => {
  if (idx && (idx+1)%3 === 1) {
   return [...accum,  "</br>", curr]
  } else return [...accum, curr]
 }, [])
.join(' ')
```

Comment: considering you are new to stack overflow, but when u ask for the next time, please post with your progress. u have to make atleast an attempt. regards s.a.